# How to move the text on the right spot?

Tags: html, css

I would like to put my text on the right side of the darker box. I want the AAAAAAAAAAAAAA' above the dark box to be on the right side. I tried it by writing it in an another container but it pushes the dark box down. Thank you!

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gray-container {
  background: #E5E5E5;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 600px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-left: 10px
}

.dark-container {
  background: #B9B9B9;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 660px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.text {
  text-align: justify margin: 20px 20px 30px 100px;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 50px;
}

.gray-banner {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 120px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #fff;
}

li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-color: #87CEFA;
  width: 200px;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

li a.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #4CAF51;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 14px 15px 15px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 5px 5px 15px 44px;
  font-family: calibri;
}

h2 {
  margin: 50px 27px 0 45px;
  font-family: calibri;
}

p {
  margin: 50px 27px 0 45px;
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://img.clipartfest.com/c61469b195ccf8a2f1090f2673258543_-of-the-nintendo-logo-nintendo-logo-clipart_1024-239.gif" />

  <ul>
    <li><a href="a.html">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="b.html">b</a></li>
    <li><a href="c.html">c</a></li>
    <li><a href="d.html">d</a></li>
    <li><a href="e.html">e</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="gray-banner">
    <h1>eeeeeeee</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="gray-container">
    <div class="text">
      <p>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dark-container">
      <h2 style="font-size: 24px; margin: 10px 5px 5px 0; "><br>hey</h2>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex` on the parent to put them in a row, then use `order: -1` on the darker box to put it visually on the left of the text.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gray-container {
  background: #E5E5E5;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 600px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-left: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.dark-container {
  background: #B9B9B9;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 660px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  order: -1;
}

.text {
  text-align: justify margin: 20px 20px 30px 100px;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 50px;
}

.gray-banner {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 120px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #fff;
}

li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-color: #87CEFA;
  width: 200px;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

li a.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #4CAF51;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 14px 15px 15px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 5px 5px 15px 44px;
  font-family: calibri;
}

h2 {
  margin: 50px 27px 0 45px;
  font-family: calibri;
}

p {
  margin: 50px 27px 0 45px;
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://img.clipartfest.com/c61469b195ccf8a2f1090f2673258543_-of-the-nintendo-logo-nintendo-logo-clipart_1024-239.gif" />

  <ul>
    <li><a href="a.html">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="b.html">b</a></li>
    <li><a href="c.html">c</a></li>
    <li><a href="d.html">d</a></li>
    <li><a href="e.html">e</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="gray-banner">
    <h1>eeeeeeee</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="gray-container">
    <div class="text">
      <p>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dark-container">
      <h2 style="font-size: 24px; margin: 10px 5px 5px 0; "><br>hey</h2>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put `float:right` in your `p` element

```
p {
    margin: 50px 27px 0 45px;
    font-family: calibri;
    font-size: 20px;
    /*add this*/
   float:right;
}
```